# Get all fields options in django

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, orm

I was wondering if it was possible to get all options of a field at once in django.

To be clearer let's say I have a model like this:

```
class TestClass(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
        unique=True)
    field1 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0),
                    MaxValueValidator(50)],
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        verbose_name=_('Little description'),
        help_text=_('Little Help text'))
    field2 = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        verbose_name=_('Verbose Name'),
        help_text=_('Help Text))
```

I know that I can do 'TestClass._meta.get_fields()' to get all fields present in my model and their type (PositiveSmallInteger, CharField for instance).

I also know that I could do 'TestClass._meta.get_field('field1').help_text' and the result would be 'Little Help text'.

What I want to know is if there is a way for a field to get all its options at once, something that could look like 'TestClass._meta.get_field('field1').options()'. Or even better for a model to get all options of all field at once.

I will override Field class for now but I was curious

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the Python's built-in [**`__dict__`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) ?
Example:

```
TestClass._meta.get_field('field1').__dict__
```